# Showing that $\mathbb{E}[ \frac{S'_n}{n \log_2 n}]$ converges to 1 for a problem related to geometric distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

We define independent random variables $X_i$ which follow the law $P(X_i = 2^k)=\frac{1}{2^k}$. We set $S_n = X_1+ \cdots +X_n$.

Since we cannot apply the law of large numbers to $S_n$, we define the auxiliary random variables $X_i ^n = X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i < n \log_2 n\}}$ and $S_n'= \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^n$.

I want to show that $\mathbb{E} \frac{S'_n}{n \log_2 n} \to 1$ and then that $Var\frac{S'_n}{n \log_2 n} \to 0$. However I fail to see how to show the first one and how the first one is related to the second one. A hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for each fixed $n$, $X_i^n$ are iid.

$$E(X_1^n)=\sum_{k:2^k\leq n\log n}2^k\dfrac{1}{2^k}\sim\log_2 n+\log_2\log n$$ therefore

$$E(\dfrac{S_n'}{n\log_2n})\sim\dfrac{n\log_2 n+n\log_2\log n}{n\log_2 n}\to1$$

Finally,

$$Var(S_n')=nVar(X_1^n)$$ due to iid-ness and

$$Var(X_1^n)\leq E(X_1^n)^2=\sum_{k:2^k\leq n\log n}2^{2k}\dfrac{1}{2^k}=\sum_{k:2^k\leq n\log n}2^k\sim\dfrac{2(n\log n-1)}{2-1}\sim 2n\log n$$

Hence $$Var(S_n')\leq 2n^2\log n$$

Thus, $$Var(\dfrac{S_n'}{n\log n})\leq \dfrac{2n^2\log n}{n^2\log^2 n}\to0$$

You should appropriately justify why $\sim$ was used using suitable limiting arguments.